# Unable to Upload Logo in Magento-2.2.4

Tags: magento2.2.4, system-configuration

I am trying to upload Logo through admin panel.

When i am trying to save configuration, it is showing an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's the Magento issue.

You have to change the code of  Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate setForcedArea method

Go to magento-root\vendor\magento\module-email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php and Replace that method code using below one.

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if (!isset($this->area)) {
        $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```